# Raj's computer monitor and keyboard

Tags: props, the-big-bang-theory

Near the beginning of season 10 episode 16: The Allowance Evaporation, the camera is at an angle that shows Raj's computer monitor and keyboard. Is that a real monitor or just a created prop for Raj's apartment? And the keyboard looks like old typewriter keys on a piece of wood. Is that a functional, purchasable keyboard?

[image]

Comment: For what it is worth the question would benefit from a screenshot.  You may think it looks like keys on a piece of wood, but lots of technical people (like developers) use custom keyboards with mechanical keys because they work much better.

Comment: https://www.spotern.com/en/spot/tv/the-big-bang-theory/54042/the-divine-keyboard-usb-keyboard-natural-wood-of-raj-koothrappali-kunal-nayyar-in-the-series-the-big-bang-theory-s10e16

Comment: @iandotkelly It does add to the character of Raj that he would have something as unique as that keyboard. The fact that it is an actual purchasable item tells me that the prop dept. didn't just cobble something together but invested time and energy into giving Raj more character.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These props speak aloud about the kind of stylish life Raj is living.

The monitor is a [Dell Crystal](https://www1.la.dell.com/ec/en/corp/peripherals/monitor_22crystalwfp/pd.aspx?refid=monitor_22crystalwfp&s=corp) which costs around $1200 and the keyboard is a [Datamancer 'Diviner Keyboard'](https://datamancer.com/product/the-diviner-keyboard/) which costs around $600.

Earlier he had a different keyboard.

[image]